# Erro ao tentar criar Jframe no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Quando vou criar uma tela usando JFrame no Eclipse mostra o erro abaixo, como posso corrigir este erro?

> The selected wizard could not be started.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.wb.swing was unable to load class org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.wizards.frame.NewJFrameWizard.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wb.swing (553).

Comment: Remova o windowbuilder e instale novamente. Isso parece ser erro de uma instalação quebrada deste plugin.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu aqui